# making a list into dictionary

Tags: python, list

suppose you have a list

```
A = ["A: 1", "B: 2", "C: 3"]
```

can you make this into a dictionary of

```
dict_A = {"A" : 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}
```

I got stuck at making the list into a dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: A = ["A: 1", "B: 2", "C: 3"]

In [2]: {k:int(v.strip()) for k,v in (i.split(":") for i in A)}
Out[2]: {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

This can effectively be unpacked as follows:

```
d = {}
for item in A:  # the first time around, item = "A: 1"
    key, value = item.split(":")  # key = "A", value = " 1"
    value = value.strip()  # value = "1"
    value = int(value)  # value = 1
    d[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = ["A: 1", "B: 2", "C: 3"]
B={}
for i in A:
    B[i[0]]=int(i[3])
print(B)

{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

the length of every string here is 4. the `i[0]` is the key like `'A'` and the `i[3]` is the value like `'1'`. converting it to `int` would give you the exact value you want, and then you just assign it to the dictionary for each key values.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One nice way of doing this:

```
A = ["A: 1", "B: 2", "C: 3"]

A = [item.split(':') for item in A]
dict_A = dict([[key, int(val)] for key, val in A])

print(dict_A)  
>>  {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

to break down each line and what it returns:

```
A = [item.split(':') for item in A]
>> [['A', ' 1'], ['B', ' 2'], ['C', ' 3']]
```

After first splitting on `:`, each index in `A` now holds a list of two items. and each index of A can be unpacked. For example: `first, second = A[1]` is the same as `first, second = A[1][0], A[1][1]` ; in both cases  `'B'` would be assigned to `first` and `'2'` to `second`
Considering that all the numbers are still strings they need to be converted to `int`, but we only want to convert the second item in each of our nested lists; this is where unpacking can be useful, as we would only apply the int conversion to the second item.

This can be done nicely in a single list comprehension

```
[[key, int(val)] for key, val in A]
>> [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
```

but, considering that you want a dictionary, we can just call `dict()` to convert into dictionary

```
dict([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]])
>> {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```